# Range.AdvancedFilter with unique parameter set duplicating first value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the Range.AdvancedFilter method to copy unique values to a separate column.
For all values except the first this works. However the first value is always duplicated:

```
'Determine source range
With Worksheets("Test")
    Set SrcRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1))
End With

'Determine target range
With Worksheets("Test")
    Set TrgtRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(2, 2))
End With

'Filter copy (unique values only) values from source to target range
SrcRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=TrgtRng, Unique:=True
```

Using the above code results in the following:

```
+--------+--------+
| Source | Target |
+--------+--------+
| test   | test   |
| test2  | test2  |
| test   | test   |
| test3  | test3  |
| test2  |        |
| test3  |        |
| test   |        |
+--------+--------+
```

I don't quite understand why it is copying the value "test" again in row 3.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Can't seem to find a solution or a reason why it's doing it in the first place.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: AF requires a header and will assume the first cell to be such.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers and the pointer at the duplicate question! You're all correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter requires a header row, which you are not supplying so it is treating the first row as headers, hence you can get duplication.